# when get values from array using keys it prints square braces in php

Tags: php, arrays

In array I stored values as follows :

```
   $quest[$qst]=$val_qst;
   print_r($quest);
```

that array contain values as follows

```
   Array ( [74] => 2 [92] => 2 [43] => 2 [91] => 2 [51] => 2)
```

When i try to print array value using key :

```
   $qq=74;
   print_r $quest[$qq];
```

But when I try to print array values using that keys(above that) in array it gives as :

```
[
```

Here what I have done wrong.

Can you help me.!!!

Comment: Use $qq='74'; instead of $qq=74;

Comment: So what is wrong with that? There are the keys only. What are the problems with `[]`?

Comment: @SunilPachlangia Will it make any difference?

Comment: how to get result. its the correct way to get an value in array using keys

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a function you need to include the parenthesis, and in the case where the function has some parameters then they need to be enclosed in the parenthesis, `print_r()` is also a function:

```
$qq=74;
print_r($quest[$qq]); // output: 2
```

Comment: here i declared that value in another variable that variable it prints as braces  `$qss=$quest[$qq]; echo $qss; //it result as [`

Comment: @Yuvaraj Please post the output of `var_dump($quest);`.

Comment: ya it gives as follows : `string(851) "Array ( [74] => 2 [92] => 2 [43] => 2 [91] => 2 [51] => 2)`

Comment: @Yuvaraj Then, your `$quest` object is **not** an array! it's a string!!

Comment: @Yuvaraj The string has `851` characters, and the character at the index of `74` is the `[` character!

Comment: @Yuvaraj How did you get the `$quest` object?

Comment: `$quest[$qst->qst_no]=$qst->qst_type;`

Comment: @Yuvaraj Not that, the one that most probably has the `$quest = ...` syntax :)